# Placing a button at a fixed position?

Tags: android

How do I place a button at a particular position (i.e at a particular pixel) on the screen, on Android?

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a bad idea. There's `AbsoluteLayout` but it's deprecated (for a good reason). Nevertheless you can use `px` values in your layout definitions and so position everything by pixel. But consider the fact that every android device differs and so has another screen resolution and density. I would recommend to use `dip` values so you get same results everywhere.

[This article](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) might be interesting...

Answer (score 1):

check out absolute layout,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html "A layout that lets you specify exact locations (x/y coordinates) of its children. Absolute layouts are less flexible and harder to maintain than other types of layouts without absolute positioning."